# Build a simple event sign up solution - problems

Tags: 2010, workflow

I am new to SP 2010 and I'm trying to build a simple sign up solution which is not that simple (at least for me) :/

I tried to implement solutions from the internet but they are either to complicated (javascript injection etc.) or not 100% cover my needs.
Here's a quick business case:

There are two lists: Events and registrations.

When user looks on the event lists he has to have possibility to click to register on this event. The button (custom command) on displayform from event list redirects to the newform/editform  of the registration lists with already prefilled information from events list. Then user only fills missing fields and clicks save. Voila.
First I tried with passing parameters within url string but that did not come up very well.
Then I found a part solution with using workflow - Action Create item in registrations. It works very well - action copies fields indicated by me to a new entry in the registrations list, however I can't find a solution to also open the form after this action (so the user fills missing data). There is no action in Workflow Editor for opening forms...

Could you advise?

Or perhaps give another approach for this case?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SPD you can add workflow parameters that have to be filled in on workflow initiation. This results in a workflow initiation form already containing the extra fields you need filled. So no need to redirect to another form.

The button to add these parameters should be in the ribbon of SPD. In your create list item action you can now use these parameter values.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot and moved building of the project ahead.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question for now, please mark as an answer. If you want more approaches I would ask a question specifically about that.